# What formula can transform the table on the left to the table on the right?

Tags: transformation

I have **Table A**, which I have to transform into **Table B**:

| Table A | Table B | Difference |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -8.00 | 0.00 | (+8) |
| -7.00 | 1.00 | (+8) |
| -6.00 | 2.00 | (+8) |
| -5.00 | 3.00 | (+8) |
| -4.00 | 4.00 | (+8) |
| -3.00 | 3.00 | (+6) |
| -2.00 | 2.00 | (+4) |
| -1.00 | 1.00 | (+2) |
| 0.00 | 0.00 | (0) |
| 1.00 | -1.00 | (-2) |
| 2.00 | -2.00 | (-4) |
| 3.00 | -3.00 | (-6) |
| 4.00 | -4.00 | (-8) |
| 5.00 | -3.00 | (-8) |
| 6.00 | -2.00 | (-8) |
| 7.00 | -1.00 | (-8) |
| 8.00 | 0.00 | (-8) |

**Table A** is a round robin between -8 and 8, with a step of 0.01 or smaller (same for Table B). 
 **Table B** is a round robin between -4 and 4, starting from 0.

The cycles look similar to the following animation (the minor cycle runs twice during one run of the major cycle): https://www.purdue.edu/freeform/me274/wp-content/uploads/sites/15/2021/11/H4A_16.gif

What formula can I use to make that transformation?

Comment: Why the formatting is not preserved after publishing the question? It looks fine in the preview, how to fix this?

Comment: Good question: i will mention this in meta.

Comment: I seem to have fixed it.

Comment: @DietrichBurde That was easier to fix than I thought it would be. Perhaps you can document what you did [at the question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34728/29335)

Comment: @DietrichBurde thank you for fixing the formatting. @ rschwieb it looks like the problem was caused by the absence of a line break before the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function is $$x + |x - 4| - |x + 4|$$

Answer (score 0):

Try $\frac{\left|x^{2}-4\left|x\right|\right|}{x}-\frac{\left|4x\right|}{x}$.